# Проблема с Ubuntu: Alloc magic is broken

Tags: ubuntu

При загрузке пишет

> Alloc magic is broken at 0x7ee6ed40 Aborted. Press any key to exit.

Когда нажимаю на любую клавишу все ребутается и повторяется... В чем дело не знаете?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проблема с загрузчиком. Скорее всего, это `GRUB`. Попробуйте его переустановить.

Comment: А как переустановить grub, если даже не войти ? с установочного? просто там я не видел про переустановку grub'a

Comment: Можно с livecd...

Answer (score -1):

Я уже расписывал переустановку grub вот [тут](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/4059/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-ubuntu-symbol-not-found-grub_env_export?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=4060#4060)